# Add dimensions in a dataset with a specific length using xarray

Tags: python, dataset, python-xarray, dimension

I'm trying to add a new dimension in an already created dataset.

My dataset contains the following dimensions:

ds (x,y)

but I would like that it presents a new dimension, with size  equal to 365:

ds(x,y,day=365).

I could expand the dimension with DataArray.expand_dims(), but i could not increase the length of it that is only 1 now.

Does anyone know to add this dimension, with this specific size using xarray?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expand_dim` and provide a dictionary (or kwargs) to it with keys being the name of the new dimension and values the length of the dimension:

`ds.expand_dims({"day":365})` or `ds.expand_dims(day=365)`

From the [documentation](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.expand_dims.html?highlight=expand#xarray.DataArray.expand_dims):

> dim (hashable, sequence of hashable, dict, or None, optional)

> Dimensions to include on the new variable. If provided as str or sequence of
> str, then dimensions are inserted with length 1. If provided as a
> dict, then the keys are the new dimensions and the values are either
> integers (giving the length of the new dimensions) or sequence/ndarray
> (giving the coordinates of the new dimensions).